# How to display file in Spring-Controller

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having an issue. This is my first time I am doing this. I have generated a random number program using Spring Rest Controller and Display in JSP.

Now what I tried is I mapped HTML file showing what I was getting in JSP. But I face this error

**No mapping Found for HTTP request with URI**

And I have tried various sites but not understanding what is wrong in that

Here I have highchart in HTML and I am refreshing the page after every 5 seconds. So, I am taking the value from server for y-axis and time is plotted on x-axis. I am also stuck in my Ajax call from the HTML file. I am not able to figure out how to take one axis value from server and other axis value from time.

I am pasting my code here---

My Controller-

```
package com.xyz.rest.temperature.controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.lucid.rest.temperature.exception.InvalidRangeException;
import com.lucid.rest.temperature.exception.NegativeNumberException;
import com.lucid.rest.temperature.util.RandomNumberGenerator;

@RestController
public class ReadingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getReading() throws NegativeNumberException,
            InvalidRangeException {
        return new Integer(new RandomNumberGenerator().generateRandomNumber(
                100, 50)).toString();
        }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/staticPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String redirect() {

          return "redirect:/jsp/hello.htm";
       }
}
```

MY dispatcher Servlet--

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.html"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.rest.temperature.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    </bean>

</beans>
```

My web.xml file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>Temperature Reading</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>hello.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>TemperatureReading</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
           <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/TemperatureReading-servlet*.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>TemperatureReading</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

My JSP is-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Random generator</title>
<%@ page language='java'%>
<%@ page import='java.*'%>
<%@ page
    import="com.xyz.rest.temperature.controller.ReadingController"%>
<%
    ReadingController obj = new ReadingController();
%>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String i = obj.getReading();
    %>
    <%=i%>
</body>
</html>
```

And my HTML file is--

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

  <title>Temprature</title>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[


$(document).ready(function() {

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'cpuhealth',
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'CPU Usage'
    },
    events: {
          load: function() {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function(){
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        $.getJSON('http://url-to-json-file/index.php', function(jsondata) {
            options.series[0].data = JSON.parse(jsondata.cpu);
        });
        }, 5000);
       }              
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value + ' %';
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Usage (%)'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'CPU Core ID#'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'CPU Core: <b>' + this.x + '</b><br>Usage <b>' + this.y + '%</b>';
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{}]
};

}

//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

So I have pasted almost everything. Please help me figure out what is the error and also How can I overcome that axis value issue in HTMl

Any help is appreciated. Please comment if you don't understand anything. Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc) and how controllers work and how they should be used.